# VBA: How to deal with passwords?

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

relatively new to VBA and looking for a solution to the following.

I am trying to make an addin within VBA that will do a lot of manual tasks for both me and my collagues. For some of the tasks it will need a username and password which is fine. My current solution is to hide a `.txt` file on our H drives (personal drives) with the password in so that we can just extract it. But lets say something goes wrong and they want mew to debug it on their screen, then I would be able to see it as a variable - which I do not want.

Is there a solution to safely using this string without compromising our security?

```
Sub ExtractData()
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String
    Dim text As String, textline As String, filedate As String
    Dim filenum As Integer

    MyFolder = "C:\directory\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "creds.txt")

    Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline

    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Encrypt the password

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your current code so we can see how you currently do it, and how it can be improved?

Comment: Added the code to read the pass

Comment: You might benefit from this article: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/password-authentication/

Comment: So you need credentials and you are using _your_ username and password, and you don't want to share this information with your _customers/collegues_. Is this a fair assessment?

Comment: Can you put the password in the hidden worksheet and password protect the workbook so that it cannot be unhidden?

Comment: No its that I and my colleagues dont want to share our password with one another. i.e. we all have different login credentials, username is fine but we can not know one another spassword